# join 2 tables from 2 different databases in R

Tags: sql, r

Can I join 2 different tables from 2 different databases inside R?

I make 2 different connections with the databases:

```
conn1<- odbcConnect("DSN", uid = "UID", pwd = "PSWD")

conn2<- odbcConnect("DSN2", uid = "UID", pwd = "PSWD")
```

Then I query from both connections a table:

```
table1 <- sqlQuery(conn1, "SELECT * from AAA")

table2 <- sqlQuery(conn2, "SELECT * from BBB")
```

My question: can I not make 1 query where I join the 2 tables on their common column?

Answer (score 1):

You usually can't join tables from different databases, also some database might allow it via replication or remote table technique, but this is not R dependent. However, once you have fetched the two tables, you can join the two dataframes using `merge` : `merge(table1, table2)`.

Comment: thank you. yes i now i can merge the tables but i thought it will be much easier if i can do that already in a query. totaly different question now, if i do merge i merge on common column by.x = 'column_1', by.y = 'column_1' but in a sql i can join on more then 1 table, is that possible in the merge function too?

Comment: Sure, pass `by` (or `by.x` or `by.y`) a vector. By default, it joins on the intersection of column names.

Comment: i mean, i have 2 common columns in table 1 and table 2 in a sql i join them by: select * from table AAA left join table BBB on collum_1 = column_1 and column_2 = column_2. i make a join on 2 columns, can i do that inte merge fuction too?

Comment: Merge uses all the common columns , so in your case 2, unless you specify otherwise