# Connect to more than one SQL server database from R in a single sqlQuery

Tags: sql, r, odbc

I'm working with R Studio. I want to use sqlQuery() to join 2 tables in sql server. The tables are in separate databases. How would i go about connecting to them both in a single sqlQuery()

For example if the two database are 'DB1' and 'DB2' the following code connects to DB1 only:

```
sqlcon <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=blah;schema=dbo;
database=DB1;trusted_connection=true')

sqlQuery(sqlcon, "my sql code for joining the tables")
```

How could i write it so 'sqlcon' is connecting to both databases at the same time?

I know i can import the sql tables separately into R and join them with R code but wanted to know if it could be done all within a single sqlQuery()

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488238/join-2-tables-from-2-different-databases-in-r

Comment: If the both DBs are hosted by the same `server=blah;` you can connect to the first one and pass a query which refers a  table at any of the server DBs with 2 part name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [join 2 tables from 2 different databases in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488238/join-2-tables-from-2-different-databases-in-r)

Comment: does MS sql server has db link?